# How can I add headings to the WYSIWYG Editor in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg

I try to add headings (h1 h2 and h3) to the WYSIWYG editor in the field product description. But I can't find a configuration option for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headings are already part of the Magento 2 WYSIWYG. Look in the "Paragraph" dropdown to the right of the "Styles" dropdown.

Comment: Aha it is there in CMS part only. But not in product description. I also need it in product description.

Comment: Oliver, click on the "WYSIWYG Editor" button just below the Description field. It will open up an editor with more menu options, including formats.